# Hibernate query output for rows that don't exist

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I've a Hibernate query:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("" +
                "SELECT d.value " +
                "FROM Table d " +
                "WHERE d.date = :date ");

        Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString())
                .setParameter("date",date);

        BigDecimal result = (BigDecimal) q.getSingleResult();

        if (result == null)
            result = BigDecimal.ZERO;

        return result;
```

When I pass date that exists in `Table` it works good, but when I pass Date that doesn't exists it returns an Exception
`javax.persistence.NoResultException: No entity found for query`

I've tried to put `@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` annotation under each filed of `Table`, but Exception is the same. How can I handle this problem?

Comment: the stringbuilder used in this way is completely useless, you are concatenating string in the stringbuilder constructor..

Comment: I know, I'll use it later on when adding some new paarmeters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

single result throws an exception when there is no result, you could either catch that exception and then return null, either q.getResultList(), and then check the list, in this way you could see if there ar duplicates too, case in which single result throws another exception.

from javadoc :

```
Throws:
    NoResultException - if there is no result
    NonUniqueResultException - if more than one result
```

handle the exception will be like :

```
 Query q = em.createQuery(sb.toString())
            .setParameter("date",date);
  try {
     BigDecimal result = (BigDecimal) q.getSingleResult();
     return result;
  } catch (NoResultException e){
     return BigDecimal.ZERO;
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no duplicates, I've two entries in Table. Isn't it possible to handle it in map?

Comment: You would like the results in a map ?

Comment: I mean there should be some annotations like @NotFound to handle similar situations

Comment: there isn't, you just have to handle the exception

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your query. That's the behavior of Query.getSingleResult() method. As Radu Toader suggested you could use Query.getResultList() or another way to handle this is to wrap it in try catch block.

```
BigDecimal result = null;
try{
   result = (BigDecimal) q.getSingleResult();
} catch(NoResultException e) {
   //log exception or throw it...
}
return result;
```